# Multivariate Interpolation Methods in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate a regular grid 3D dataset in TensorFlow (I want it to be differentiable). However, I've only been able to find a trilinear method so far using the tensorflow_graphics library; is there a different TF interpolation implementation (e.g. spline, tricubic) whose first order derivative is continuous?

Comment: Can you please give a code example of what you've tried? Or point a link to the documentation of the triliear method you're referring to that doesn't work? I'm not sure I completely understand your question and I'd like to help, thanks.

Comment: The trilinear approach I referred to can be found here: [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/graphics/api_docs/python/tfg/math/interpolation/trilinear/interpolate). The code actually works fine, but the problem I'm trying to solve involves computing the first order derivatives (which is piecewise because it's the derivative of a linear function). What I'm wondering is if there are any other multivariate interpolations on TensorFlow (such as spline) that might be suitable for regular grids, thanks for your time!